# Underline error

Tags: evil, osx

When booting emacs, I get this strange error:

```
See https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection/issues/60 for more details.
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/carolynknight-serrano/.emacs.d/init.el’:

error: Invalid face underline, :style, wave, :color, nil
```

For context, I'm on macos and installed emacs-app from macports.

Comment: It's telling you there's an error in your init file.  The message should help you locate it, but you can also recursively bisect the file (comment out half, then half of half, and so on until you identify the problem).

Comment: Hmm that's odd because this exact setup worked on Linux and OpenBSD